# Fastest way to capture what's on the screen in C

Tags: c, windows, screenshot

My goal is to write a program that would capture the screen in an efficient way.
Little twist, the screen will not be saved. My program will do various check on it (pixel's colors in  some area.. etc).

The program will run in windows, and will need to take(and analyze) as many screenshot as possible per second, and will not be used in games. (That imply that I need the whole screen, like pressing prntscreen. It's not a problem if that fail in fullscreen game.)

All propositions are welcome, and I'd be glad to share any missing details.

**Edit**
As I wrote in the comment, capturing the screen for storing purpose is really common and easy to find. 
I asked to be sure to not miss any method of capturing the screen without storing it at all.
The program will look the screen, take some decision then will quickly go to the next frame.

Comment: What's wrong with the results you get from [googling "Windows screen capture api"](https://www.google.com/search?q=WINDOWS+SCREEN+CAPTURE+API)?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5051/Various-methods-for-capturing-the-screen
"When performance is not an issue use GDI"
But for DirectX I think it's only for games.
I will look the last one proposed.
I realy wanted to know if I was missing a good method of getting the screen without storing it.

Comment: Okay, for an alternate, how about [googling "open source screen capture"](https://www.google.com/search?q=open+source+screen+capture)?

Comment: Well, only relevant link here is http://sourceforge.net/directory/graphics/graphics/graphics-capture/screencapture/ which is a search.. I tried to look for open source in C, but it's too hard to find a specific language.
But yes I already tried to find the source of a quick and lightweight recorder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I'm sorry but I miss your point.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps look into [SDL](http://libsdl.org)

A guick google returned this screenshot code for SDL: http://lists.libsdl.org/pipermail/sdl-libsdl.org/2000-August/011387.html